# How to count overlapped objects and objects with more than 1 color?

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing

I want to create a program that can count the number of objects in an image. All went smoothly except for the images that have:

1. objects that have more than 1 color.
2. overlapping objects.

Following is my program that can only count the number of objects in an image where the object has only 1 color and not overlapped. I use the function `bwlabel`.

```
a=imread('Tumpukan Buku2.jpg');
a_citra_keabuan = rgb2gray(a);
threshold = graythresh(a_citra_keabuan);
a_bww = im2bw(a_citra_keabuan,threshold);
a_bw=~a_bww;
[labeled,numObjects]=bwlabel(a_bw);
[m,n]=size(a_bw);
s = regionprops(labeled, 'Centroid');
B = bwboundaries(a_bw);

imshow(a_bw)
hold on
for k = 1:numel(s)
    c = s(k).Centroid;
    text(c(1), c(2), sprintf('%d', k), ...
        'HorizontalAlignment', 'center', ...
        'VerticalAlignment', 'middle');
end
for k = 1:length(B)
    boundary = B{k};
    plot(boundary(:,2), boundary(:,1), 'g', 'LineWidth', 0.2)
end
hold off
```

Here is the result for an image that has objects in 1 color:

[image: RESULT]

and here is the wrong result for the image with object that has > 1 color and overlapped:

[image: WRONG RESULT]

How to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to clearly define your input data- what types of objects do you want to detect (books, people, any types of objects?), what is the range of environmental conditions (smooth background vs. textured, lighting, perspective).

Then try out [various image segmentation techniques](http://www.mathworks.com/discovery/image-segmentation.html) and seeing what works for your range of input data.  There is no "right" answer - it all depends on your data.

You might also try to incorporate *prior* information- things that you know when evaluating a scene, that a computer will not know by just evaluating pixels.

For example, maybe all objects are of some minimum size.  So your algorithm can filter to only return objects having `pixelArea > minArea`. Maybe you only expect one objet of each color.  So if the color histogram of two detected objects matches to within a given tolerance, consider them to be the same object.

Comment: So, i cannot do a segmentation for any types of objects?
and i have to focus just for objects that have same structur.
cannot segment a object like circle with object overlapped book with same code of matlab?